# Core data modeling many-to-many

Tags: core-data, many-to-many

I have the following:

**Deal**, **Contact and DealContact**. A **Deal** can have many **Contacts**. A **Contact** can belong to many **Deals**. **DealContact** is used to maintain both of this using two relationships: **to-one** called **deal** and a **to-many** called **contacts**. I also need to store a primary contact separately in **DealContact**. This is another **to-one** relationship called **primary**.

**Contact** then has an **inverse to-many** to **DealContact** called **dealcontacts** and a **to-one** called **primarydealcontact**. A **Deal** does not have an inverse to **DealContact**. A deal also does not have a direct relationship to **Contact**.

In SQL I would've modeled this using a join table. I'm trying to carry this over using **DealContact** as I need additional properties stored besides just the **Deal** and associated **Contacts**.

Any suggestions on if this setup is correct or perhaps an easier setup would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that after redesigning my Core Data model and removing the DealContact entity I found that I was actually not passing along the DealContact object (which had the core data accessors) to removeContactsObject from the set. After clearing this issue (which was greatly simplified by removing DealContact entity from the model all together) [deal removeContactsObject:oneContact] worked exactly as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Let me put things down with a small old school ASCII model.

```
Deal
- stuff

Contact
- stuff
- dealcontacts ->> DealContact
- primarydealcontact -> DealContact

DealContact
- stuff
- deal -> Deal
- contacts ->> Contact
- primary -> Contact
```

All right.

This stuff is not very coredataish.

First thing first.

`Deal`: I do not see the point not to have an inverse relationship to `DealContact.deal`. You'll have to handle the `Deal` deletions manually to ensure there is no `DealContact` left without a related `Deal`. That inverse relationship costs you almost nothing.

`Contact`: why is `Contact.primarydealcontract` a to-one relationship? You sure a `Contact` can't be the primary contact of several `Deal`?

Details all that anyway. Let's discuss what is not very coredataish. `DealContact`.

What's the point of that entity? Basically, you have `Deal` connected to many `Contact`, including a primary `Contact`. The additional fields in `DealContact` are most certainly related either to the `Deal` or a `Contact`, so why a dedicated entity for them?

This is how I see the entities:

```
Deal
- stuff // from Deal & from DealContact
- contacts ->> Contact
- primarycontact -> Contract

Contact
- stuff
- deals ->> Deal.contacts
- dealsprimary ->> Deal.primarycontact
```

Core Data will create the necessary relationship tables to keep track of the many-to-many relationships. Core Data does that very well.

Of course I do not know all the details of your application, so my suggestion is, well, a suggestion. Nothing more. It may suits your needs, or not. But considering what you told, it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent suggestion. This greatly helped remove the complexity of my model and simplified the app overall. This did not however resolve the issue. See below for solution.